# sending application version with Push Notification IOS

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging, phonegap-pushplugin

My Inglês is not very good, but I'll try to explain.

To send a new version of the application with push notification, you must select the X CODE - Build Phases, Provisioning Profile option in my push production certificate ??

issue 2

I'm using google GCM, Developing it worked fine, but now in production can not upload my certificate push production in gcm he says (The Bundle ID in the certificate does not match the Bundle ID you entered.) This error will not be by que I sent my version with the no provisioning profile with my certificate ??

The apple should not stop it?

Comment: Hi, please limit your questions to one topic per question. The questions are not clear to me, perhaps an IOS developer understand them better.

Answer (score 0):

Apple APN has nothing to do with GCM, it is completely incompatible with it.
As soon as you create a new App APN certificate, you must use a new provisioning profile: the previous one won't include APN support.
APN support is added automatically, provided you use the right provisioning profile, you don't need to touch any setting, save adding the push handling code in your app source code with XCode.
This applies to both production and sandbox.

With Apple iOS Push Notifications, or Apple APN for short, you use two separate servers and certificates for "sandbox" (debug) and "production".
APN notifications don't work within the simulator.
If you use the Sandbox outside debug mode, it won't work.

If you use notifications in production, or deploy AD Hoc versions of your app, you must use the PRODUCTION servers and the production APN certificate, even if you are using an Ad Hoc compile to test the app.

You must set up your App APN certificates within iTunes Connect, in Apple Developer Portal, and then install these Push certificates within your own APN server (which will comunicate with Apple's Push servers).
The path specified in these certificates must match your App's and can't be generic or team.

Your own server APN server communicates with Apple APNS servers. You can't send Push Notifications to iOS devices directly, without passing trough Apple servers first. You do so using a protocol.

You can find a technical description of APN service [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html)

Several pre made APN servers and APN libraries exist, for several programming languages and operating systems.

If you don't want to deploy your own, you can use a third party service, e.g. Urban Airship.